# Tips to make Codename One PeerComponents z-ordering working

Tags: codenameone

I created a `PeerComponent`, that is a port in Codename One of the Horizon Camera SDKs. At the moment, it simply shows a live-preview of the camera.

I tried to add a `Label` over the `PeerComponent`: the `Label` is on top only in Android. On iOS, the `Label` is on bottom (that means invisible).

I've done a lot of trials to get a correct z-ording on iOS, without success.

My question is which tips, suggestions or checks can I do to make z-ordering working properly on iOS also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it should "just work", there is no special treatment. I think horizon paints in an area we rely on and doesn't paint when we expect it to. Looking at their [sample code](https://github.com/HorizonCamera/HorizonSDK-iOS/blob/master/Examples/AdvancedHorizonSDKDemo/AdvancedHorizonSDKDemo/ViewController.m) I see that they reference top and bottom elements which might allow working around this.